# Stack: How can I use a multi-package dependency in `Setup.hs`?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a `stack` multi-package project where the "multi-package" is `zip-conduit-0.2.2.2` (I needed to tweak some dependency versions to get it to compile with `nightly-2015-10-12`).

I use `zip-conduit` in the main package and I also want to in `Setup.hs` in order to be able to package up zip files.

I have `build-type: Custom` in my cabal file and `stack build` attempts to build `Setup.hs`. The problem is that building `Setup.hs` cannot find the dependency `zip-conduit-0.2.2.2`.

Can I use a multi-package dependency in `Setup.hs`? If so how? and if not, what is my alternative?

Note: I have seen this reference https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/899, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the [explicit-setup-deps](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md#explicit-setup-deps) setting to true for that package. It's unfortunate that Stack can't handle this situation automatically, but without dependency information in .cabal files, there seems to be no alternative.

See the linked issues from the documentation if you're interested in the history here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to declare package dependencies for Setup.hs itself.

Some ideas:

- Require that the dependent packages have already been installed.
- Have `Setup.hs` shell out to an external command to perform the zipping, and just require that the external command has to exist.
- Make the installer program an additional exe target in the cabal file. Before proceeding with the build of the library, Setup.hs can build the installer program target, then build the library, then use the built installer exe to install the library.